# Only variables can be passed by reference in array_push

Tags: php, arrays

I want to insert million rows in database table and I'm trying to insert by 1000 rows each time by pushing values in array.

```
$pdo = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=dbname;', 'root', '');

$batch_size = 1000;

$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`sector`,`keyword`,`location`,`position`) VALUES ";
// Add 1,000 value lists
$sql .= str_repeat("(?,?,?,?),", $batch_size-1);
$sql .= "(?,?,?,?),";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
for ($i = 0; $i < (1000000/$batch_size); $i++) {
    $vals = array();
    for ($j = 0; $j < $batch_size; $j++) {
    array_push("5","5","5","5"); // <-- error
    }
    $stmt->execute($vals);
}
```

I get error: Only variables can be passed by reference in line: (array_push...)
Can you suggest solution? Thanks

Comment: try Multiple Values Insert with PDO Prepared Statements

Comment: You forgot to tell `array_push` which array you want to push those values onto

Comment: You right! My line should be: array_push($vals,"5","5","5","5");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the array you're trying to push in.

The [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) tell you:

> ### Parameters
>
> array
>
> - The input array.
>
> ...
>
> - The values to push onto the end of the array.

You insert 4 parameters in this part: `array_push("5","5","5","5");`

You need to add the array you want to array_push. Like this:

```
array_push($vals, "5", "5","5","5");
```